# Label Text proprety would not change

Tags: c#, winforms

So I am trying to show the progress of my application from Form2 to Form1, using a huge Label(located on Form1), but the Text proprety of the Label doesn't change using my code.

There is a download process on executed via Form2 and when it finishes I want a label on Form1 to be updated to notify the user of a completion.

Here is the code:
in Form1:

```
public string LabelText
{
    get
    {
        return this.label1.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        this.label1.Text = value;
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

in Form2:

```
private void DLClient(string link, string saveloc)
{
    webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
    webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadDataCompleted);
    webClient.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(link));

}

private void webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
    double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;

    progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
}

private void webClient_DownloadDataCompleted(Object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] downloadedBytes = e.Result;
    Stream file = File.Open(saveloc, FileMode.Create);
    file.Write(downloadedBytes, 0, downloadedBytes.Length);
    file.Close();
    webClient.Dispose();
    (new Form1()).LabelText = "Desired Text";//the changing code
    Close();
```

I don't think there is a use for the calling code of Form2 within Form1 to be posted because it's pretty much working 100%.

Comment: So when the download completes, do you have Form1 already visible? Or you need to open the form1 when the download completes from Form2.

Comment: aaah yes, i used `Frm.ShowDialog()`, so it keeps the Form1 visible in the background but frozen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass Form2 THE instance of Form1, like in form2's class constructor.

Don't instantiate a new (invisible) Form1, like you're doing here:

```
(new Form1()).LabelText
```

---

The solution:

```
private Form form1;

public Form2(Form theForm1) {
form1 = theForm1;
}
```

...

```
((Form1)form1).LabelText = "It works";
```

The calling code:

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(this);
```

"this" is the Form1 instance.

Comment: Ok so this comment is after reading the 2015-07-23 16:40:09 Edit, the code doesn't work, the `form1` in `form1.LabelText = "It works"` doesn't give out an option named `LabelText` although it exists in Form1.

Comment: Sorry you will need to cast it, 2 secs. Ok see the edit I made: ((Form1)form1).LabelText = "It works";

Answer (score 1):

While setting the label text, you are initializing new instance of `Form1`, so the desired text is actually being set in `new Form1` and not in the Form that is already open. These are two different instances and do not know each other.

Ideally I would do this by creating an event for this say, `DownloadCompleted` or something like this; raise the event in Form2 and handle this event in Form1.

Another quick option would be to have an instance of Form1 in Form2, then you can assign this property just before showing up the Form2. Something like this -

```
var objForm2 = new Form2();
objForm2.objForm1 = this;
objForm2.ShowDialog();
```

...and then in Form2 -

```
objForm1 .LabelText = "Desired Text";//the changing code
```

Comment: It didn't work sadly, because objForm1 doesn't have LabelText as one of it's propreties

Comment: @Omarrrio: You can create a property like this - `public Form1 objForm1 { get; set; }` in Form2